# Prolog logic puzzle

Tags: prolog, logic

I have the next problem: there are given four lists. The first list contains codes for one or more tables. The second list contains numbers, representing the number of apples on each table. The third list contains one or more children names and the forth contains how many apples each child will receive.

For example: `[a],[3],[c,d],[2,1]`; `a` is the code of the table and `3` is the number of apples on it. `c` and `d` are the names of the children and `2` and `1` are the number of apples `c`, respectively `d` receive.

Find out a possible way each children will receive his apples from any table given.

For the example 1 I gave the only possible solution is: child `c` will take two apples from `a` and child `d` will take one.
The output should be like this: `[[a,c,2],[a,d,1]]`.

There is no limit for the number of tables and children and there will always be on the tables exactly the number of apples the children need.

I know I have to come with some code but I really have no idea how to begin. Some hints on how to start would be appreciated.

Comment: this is not clear at all. before any code, formulate your problem so it can be understood by others. your example is not helping, as you talk of "tables" (plural) but only show one. in any other tag this would get downvoted and closed.

Answer (score 1):

To start, try to serve a *single* request. Could be as simple as

```
update([K|Ks],[V|Vs],N,[U|Us],[take(T,K)|TKs]) :-
    N > 0,
    T is min(N,V),
    M is N-T,
    U is V-T,
    update(Ks, Vs, M, Us, TKs).
/*update([_|Ks],[_|Vs],N,Us,TKs) :-
    N > 0,
    update(Ks, Vs, N, Us, TKs).*/
update(_,Vs,N,Vs,[]) :-
    N =< 0.
```

That is, given `N` apples requested, take as much as possible from table `K`, leaving on it `U` apples.

Uncommenting the 2^ clause would answer a slightly different question: instead of `Find out a possible way...` would show `Find out all possible ways...`

Then try to apply to all children...